# Unicenta card terminal

Tags: payment, credit-card

Is there way how to connect our PinPad card terminal to Unicenta ? I cannot find any info about hw connection to unicenta.

We have this: 
http://ingenico.us/terminals/ipp220/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per their FAQ, they do not support direct communication with terminals (pinpad).

[FAQ](http://unicenta.com/faqs/)

> Q: Does uniCentra oPOS handle Credit Cards?
>
> A: We don’t integrate with directly attached card payment terminals at this time.

Also, the only payment peripheral listed is the "Magnetic Card Reader".

You may want to research the existing integrated gateways to see if they have a direct terminal communication solution.

Comment: This answer would be better if the results of the research would be included here.

Comment: @Henno I do not understand your comment. I was telling them to research other integrated options if he wanted a hardware option. I could give recommendations on who to use but that would be purely my opinion.

Comment: I was suggesting that the answer would be more useful if it included a list of what could be used.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the feedback. I was trying to not give opinions, only answer their question. Of course I think Axia Technologies product is a great integration to use for card present payment processing but there is also Stripe, Open Edge, as well as direct to most banks (Chase Paymentech or BAMS [Bank of America Merchant Services].